# Difference between javax.inject.Singleton and javax.ejb.Singleton

Tags: java, singleton, ejb, java-ee-7, inject

im little confused. What is the exact difference between `javax.inject.Singleton` and `javax.ejb.Singleton`?

Answer (score 20):

I found a plausible explanation [here](https://developer.jboss.org/message/777882#777882):

> By default, `javax.ejb.Singleton` session beans are transactional (section 13.3.7 of the EJB 3.1 specification) and require acquisition of an exclusive lock for every business method invocation (sections 4.8.5.4 and 4.8.5.5).
>
> In contrast, a `javax.inject.Singleton` is not transactional and does not support container-managed concurrency (the major consequence being that no locking scheme is implemented by the container). [...]
>
> If you don't need EJB features, stick with `@ApplicationScoped` (`javax.inject.Singleton` is not defined by CDI, and its semantics are therefore not governed by that specification).

To reduce future confusion, I use this small unit test (first level package name needs to be replaced):

```
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.noClasses;

import com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaClasses;
import com.tngtech.archunit.core.importer.ClassFileImporter;

import org.junit.Test;

public class SingletonTest {

    /** requires com.tngtech.archunit:archunit-junit:0.4.0 */
    @Test
    public void detectWrongSingletonAnnotation() {

        final ClassFileImporter importer = new ClassFileImporter();
        final JavaClasses classes = importer.importPackages("first_level_package");

        noClasses().should().beAnnotatedWith("javax.inject.Singleton")
                .as("Please use javax.ejb.Singleton instead of javax.inject.Singleton.")
                .check(classes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since accepted answer didn't solve my problem I post my own answer. It won't be as good as article by Adam Bien but definitely will be more practical:

Consider following code:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class DatabaseConnection {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("init");
    }

    public ChampionComp getFirstRecord() {
        return new ChampionComp("Ashe", "Teemo", "Warwick", 
                "Blitzcrank", "Syndra", "Anivia", "Brand", "Rammus", "Xin Zhao", "Irelia");
    }

}
```

And this REST service:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/champions")
public class ChampionsAPI {

    @Inject
    private DatabaseConnection db;

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getClichedMessage() {
        ChampionComp comp = db.getFirstRecord();
        return comp.toString();
    }
}
```

Using `javax.ejb.Singleton` this code works just fine. The `DatabaseConnection` instance is created once and injected to REST service.
However when replacing `ejb` in import with `inject` you would receive NPE in ChampionsAPI class while accessing db field - that's because your Singleton was not created (for some reason, maybe because one need to make use of interfaces while using `javax.inject.Singleton` ? ).

Comment: This is not a problem of Singleton package but rather a CDI discovery issue. CDI is not "activated" in your case. If CDI is properly activated (using beans.xml , etc.) injection will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In simple clarity:

javax.ejb.Singleton is an annotation used to create an @Singleton EJB (as opposed to @Sateless EJB or @Stateful EJB)

On the other hand, javax.inject.Singleton is an annotation used to create a CDI with singleton scope

So basically, one creates a singleton EJB while the other creates a CDI with singleton scope